# Delphi: gradient like in tool bar

Tags: delphi, colors, toolbar, gradient

I need a tool bar with a gradient, but I want normal buttons without a hot track. I do as a TToolBar class do:

My code:

```
procedure TForm7.ToolBar1CustomDraw(Sender: TToolBar; const ARect: TRect;
      var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
 GradientFillCanvas(sender.Canvas, clWindow, $00D6D6D6, ARect, gdVertical); //a GraphUtil unit
end;
```

Tool bar's function from a `ComCtrls` unit:

```
function TToolBar.GradientDrawToolBar(const ARect: TRect): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if gdoGradient in GradientDrawingOptions then
    GradientFillCanvas(Canvas, FGradientStartColor, FGradientEndColor,
      ARect, GradientDirection);
end;
```

Why do I have different results?

[image]

### Added:

`GetShadowColor(clBtnFace, -25) = $00D6D6D6` for me

Comment: -1 Those colors I see are exactly the same. Only the height of the drawn sections differ. What is your question exactly? Is it how to adjust the rect?

Comment: @NGLN , right, a stupid question :)

Comment: Not exactly. The lower ends in $00D5D5D5 and is, indeed higher (63 pixels) than the top one (53 pixels).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the source for ComCtrls, the value for FGradientEndColor is GetShadowColor(clBtnFace, -25), which is based on a system color and may change depending on Windows appearance settings. Try using the same value in your custom draw code instead of $00D6D6D6.

Comment: Thanks, but $00D6D6D6 = GetShadowColor(clBtnFace, -25) for my Windows, the same (I saw GetShadowColor(clBtnFace, -25) in ComCtrls and checked it). Do you have the same colors on both tool bars?

Comment: could you delete your answer, I'll delete the question. Thanks!

Comment: That may be, but you should use the function for the case someone changes that colour in the settings. On the top tool bar, the shadow colour is $00D6D6D6, on the bottom one it is $00D5D5D5, according to my graphics program.

Comment: @Rudy: That is essentially the same colour. I am confident that the tiny discrepancy is simply due to subtle and natural numerical issues caused by the fact that the heights of the rects differ.

Comment: @Andreas: I know. But one wonders how come it is not $D6D6D6 exactly.

Comment: @maxfax: you should be able to delete your question regardless of whether answers are there (deleted or not).